# Load dark theme with JS before page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a dark-light mode switcher for my website but I ran into a problem. I have to be honest: I don't know much about JS so the code you will see here is probably super ugly and messy. I just copypasted some snippets I found online.

So, my problem is that when I turn on the dark mode and click on another page, it flickers. On page load, it still starts with the light theme and then switches to the dark one. I have no clue why it's happening. Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Here's a fiddle with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/zsoltszilvai/qctpyo2s/3/

```
console.clear();

let trans = () => {
  document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition');
  }, 1000)
}

var checkbox = document.querySelector('input');

var checkboxValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkboxValues')) || {};

$checkboxes = $(":checkbox");

$checkboxes.on("change", function() {
  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    //console.log(this.checked);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("checkboxValues", JSON.stringify(checkboxValues));
});

$.each(checkboxValues, function(key, value) {
  $("#" + key).prop('checked', value);
  if ($('#' + key).attr('name') == 'mode') {
    if (value) {
      trans();
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
    } else {
      trans();
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
    }
  }
});



/* DARK MODE */


var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name=mode]');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark')
  } else {
    trans()
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light')
  }
})
```

Someone mentioned that I could try putting some JS code in the head - which is considered to be bad practice. I tried it anyway but it didn't work for some reason.

I also got a tip that storing the data in a cookie instead of the locale storage could do the trick. The problem is that I don't necessarily want to use cookies for this if there's another solution.

Comment: You forget to close `@media (min-width: 12em) {` bracket. Then at last in `body` `CSS` add some transitions like `transition: all 0.4s ease;`

Comment: thanks but these won't solve this problem unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tutorial that solves the problem: https://derekkedziora.com/blog/dark-mode

In the head:

```
const theme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
if (theme === "dark") {
document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
}
```

On the bottom of the page:

```
const userPrefers = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('content'); 

if (theme === "dark") {
    document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
} else if (theme === "light") {
    document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
} else if  (userPrefers === "dark") {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
    document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
} else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
    window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
    document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
}

function modeSwitcher() {
    let currentMode = document.documentElement.getAttribute('data-theme');
    if (currentMode === "dark") {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
        document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Dark Mode";
    } else {
        document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');
        window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
        document.getElementById("theme-toggle").innerHTML = "Light Mode";
    }
}
```